# C# resident program to monitor and disallow user to change a particular type of file's file extension

Tags: c#, monitor, file-extension

Is it possible to write a c# resident program to monitor and disallow user to change a particular type of file's file extension?

For example, whenever a user wants to change "abc.doc"'s file extension to "abc.jpg" . The monitoring program will change it back or not allow it.

Please give me some advice and web link for C# code sample.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use FileSystemWatcher class to watch files if their content didnt change. Example is here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F

It allows to be notified about any change of watched file (like content or filename change).